# awk: print duplicate entries after a condition is met

Tags: awk, duplicates

I have a large file with different types of entries, separated by tabs:

```
## HEADER 1
## HEADER 2
## HEADER 3
#Col1   Col2    Col3
1_222_A/G   value1  ISO
1_222_A/G   value1  ISO
1_222_A/G   value1  ISO
1_222_A/G   value1  CANON
1_506_C/T   value2  ISO
1_506_C/T   value2  CANON
1_245_A/T   value3  SINGLE
2_1156_C/G  value4  ISO
2_1156_C/G  value4  ISO
2_1221_A/T/C    value5  ISO
2_1221_A/T/C    value5  ISO
2_1221_A/T/C    value5  CANON
2_1221_A/T/C    value5  CANON
3_787_G/T   value6  ISO
3_99089_A/C value7  ISO
3_99089_A/C value7  ISO
3_99089_A/C value7  CANON
4_12_T/C    value8   SINGLE
4_167_A/G   value9  ISO
4_167_A/G   value9  CANON
4_167_A/G   value9  CANON
```

I want to print everything but change the $3 value to "CANON_DUPL" in those entries meeting these conditions:

1. NOT starting with #.
2. $3 value must be "CANON".
3. $1 value must be duplicated.

**So the final table must be:**

```
## HEADER 1
## HEADER 2
## HEADER 3
#Col1   Col2    Col3
1_222_A/G   value1  ISO
1_222_A/G   value1  ISO
1_222_A/G   value1  ISO
1_222_A/G   value1  CANON
1_506_C/T   value2  ISO
1_506_C/T   value2  CANON
1_245_A/T   value3  SINGLE
2_1156_C/G  value4  ISO
2_1156_C/G  value4  ISO
2_1221_A/T/C    value5  ISO
2_1221_A/T/C    value5  ISO
2_1221_A/T/C    value5  CANON_DUPL
2_1221_A/T/C    value5  CANON_DUPL
3_787_G/T   value6  ISO
3_99089_A/C value7  ISO
3_99089_A/C value7  ISO
3_99089_A/C value7  CANON
4_12_T/C    value8  SINGLE
4_167_A/G   value9  ISO
4_167_A/G   value9  CANON_DUPL
4_167_A/G   value9  CANON_DUPL
```

---

I tried it using awk but I only got to meet the two first conditions:

```
> awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}; !/#/$3~"CANON"{$3="CANON_DUPL"} {print $0}' file.txt
## HEADER 1
## HEADER 2
## HEADER 3
#Col1   Col2    Col3
1_222_A/G   value1  ISO
1_222_A/G   value1  ISO
1_222_A/G   value1  ISO
1_222_A/G   value1  CANON_DUPL #should not be modified
1_506_C/T   value2  ISO
1_506_C/T   value2  CANON_DUPL #should not be modified
1_245_A/T   value3  SINGLE
2_1156_C/G  value4  ISO
2_1156_C/G  value4  ISO
2_1221_A/T/C    value5  ISO
2_1221_A/T/C    value5  ISO
2_1221_A/T/C    value5  CANON_DUPL
2_1221_A/T/C    value5  CANON_DUPL
3_787_G/T   value6  ISO
3_99089_A/C value7  ISO
3_99089_A/C value7  ISO
3_99089_A/C value7  CANON_DUPL #should not be modified
4_12_T/C    value8  SINGLE
4_167_A/G   value9  ISO
4_167_A/G   value9  CANON_DUPL
4_167_A/G   value9  CANON_DUPL
```

I don't know if solutions out from awk are easier to implement.
Any thoughts?

**Note: Edited to reflect better the file structure**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. This will require memory(for large datasets) since its reading Input_file twice. In case your actual Input_file is tab separated then add change `awk` to `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` in following code.

```
awk '
(FNR==1 || FNR==2 || FNR==3 ){
  if(++count<=3){ print }
  next
}
FNR==NR{
  arr[$1,$3]++
  next
}
arr[$1,$3]>1 && $0!~/^#/ && $3=="CANON"{
  $3="CANON_DUPL"
}
1
'  Input_file  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                     ##Starting awk program from here.
(FNR==1 || FNR==2 || FNR==3 ){            ##Checking condition if line is 1 2 or 3 here.
  if(++count<=3){ print }                 ##If count is lesser or equals to 3 then print it.
  next                                    ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
FNR==NR{                                  ##Checking condition which will be TRUE when 1st time Input_file is being read.
  arr[$1,$3]++                            ##Creating arr with index of $1,$3 and keep increasing its value by 1 here.
  next                                    ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
arr[$1,$3]>1 && $0!~/^#/ && $3=="CANON"{  ##Checking condition if arr with 1st,3rd field value is greater than 1 AND line not starting with # AND 3rd column is CANON then do following.
  $3="CANON_DUPL"                         ##Set 3rd field to CANON_DUPL here.
}
1                                         ##printing current line here.
' Input_file  Input_file                  ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: It does not work properly, since I just realized that almost every entry is repeated from 2 to 6 times, with both CANON and ISO values in $3 (i.e., 1_222_A/G - ISO exists 5 times and and 1_222_A/G - CANON exists once), so at the end this command detects every CANON as duplicated (following the example, I do not wish to mark 1_222_A/G - CANON as CANON_DUPL, as it only appears once).
I edited the question to clarificate this.

Comment: @ALG, ok please try following once `awk '(FNR==1 || FNR==2 || FNR==3 ){if(++count<=3){ print };next} FNR==NR{arr[$1,$3]++;next};arr[$1,$3]>1 && $0!~/^#/ && $3=="CANON"{$3="CANON_DUPL"}1' file file` and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: @ALG, I have edited my answer also, output is coming same as your shown samples, please do check it once and let me know in case of any queries, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-pass solution:

*parse.awk*

```
NR<=4 { print; next }
NR==5 { P1=$1; P2=$2; P3=$3; next }
$1 == P1 && $3 == "CANON" && P3 == "CANON" { $3 = P3 = "CANON_DUPL" }
{ print P1, P2, P3; P1=$1; P2=$2; P3=$3 }
END { print P1, P2, P3 }
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f parse.awk infile OFS='\t'
```

Output:

```
## HEADER 1
## HEADER 2
## HEADER 3
#Col1   Col2    Col3
1_222_A/G   value1  ISO
1_222_A/G   value1  ISO
1_222_A/G   value1  ISO
1_222_A/G   value1  CANON
1_506_C/T   value2  ISO
1_506_C/T   value2  CANON
1_245_A/T   value3  SINGLE
2_1156_C/G  value4  ISO
2_1156_C/G  value4  ISO
2_1221_A/T/C    value5  ISO
2_1221_A/T/C    value5  ISO
2_1221_A/T/C    value5  CANON_DUPL
2_1221_A/T/C    value5  CANON_DUPL
3_787_G/T   value6  ISO
3_99089_A/C value7  ISO
3_99089_A/C value7  ISO
3_99089_A/C value7  CANON
4_12_T/C    value8  SINGLE
4_167_A/G   value9  ISO
4_167_A/G   value9  CANON_DUPL
4_167_A/G   value9  CANON_DUPL
```